# phpunit generate coverage report in html format for specific folder only

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I want to generate coverhtml for my classes only currently I am using command like,

```
    phpunit --coverage-html=../../coverage ../../test/assertion.php
```

but it is testing the code in the vendor folder as well.

Comment: Use the bootstrap or XML file for options to include/exclude directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the XML file, you can include the directories you want to process, and exclude the ones you do not.

```
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".class">.</directory>
        <directory suffix=".fn">.</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">.</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory>ExternalLibraries</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```